# How to Remove Header in LaTex

Tags: latex

I would like to not show the name of each chapter on the header of its each page. I also like to have nothing in the headers for abstract, acknowledgement, table of content, list of figures and list of tables. But I currently have the header on each page, for example:

[image]

Thanks and regards!

---

EDIT:

I just replaced `\thispagestyle{botcenter}` with `\thispagestyle{plain}`. The latter is said to clear the header (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout), but it does not. How shall I do?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

I now just realized it could be the fancy pagestyle that shows the header.

```
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\fancyhf{}  
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}  
\lhead{\leftmark}  
\cfoot{\thepage}  
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% Redefine ``plain'' style for chapter boundaries
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields  
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} % except the center  
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

How can I remove header and keep the footer? I think footer is needed to show the page number right?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

My pdf file also has no page numbering for the first page of Table of Content, List of Tables and List of Figures. Is this normal? If it is not, how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be experimenting with `\pagestyle` and, if that does not provide enough control, the `fancyhdr` package.  How they will interact with what I surmise is a custom document class I am not sure.

Comment: I just replaced \thispagestyle{botcenter} with \thispagestyle{plain}. The latter is said to clear the header (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout), but it does not. How shall I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe \thispagestyle{empty}, I think plain means that the headers and footers default to 'normal'.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I now just realized it could be the fancy pagestyle that shows the header. See my edit. How can I remove header and keep the footer? I think footer is needed to show the page number right?

Comment: You would set the header to be empty, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

I did this by `\fancyhead{}`, along with `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT*:  I cleared my other ramblings.  The only thing you need to do is remove the `\leftmark` from your `\lhead`.

Comment: Thanks, Svante! Your code clears the text in the headers but introduces a line from left to right in the headers. My pdf file also has no page numbering for the first page of Table of Content, List of Tables and List of Figures. Is this normal? If it is not, how to fix it? Thanks!